# Find an equivalent of $\sum_{n=1}^{\phi(x)}n^{-n/\alpha}x^n$ with $\phi(x)$ as $x\to +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Notations :**

Let $\alpha >0$ be a positive real number and let's consider $\phi : \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb N^*$ defined as follow:
$$
\phi(x) = \lfloor e^{\alpha} x^\alpha\rfloor
$$

We note $f : x \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{\phi(x)}n^{-n/\alpha}x^n$ for $x\geq 0$.

**The problem:**

Find an equivalent of $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\phi(x)}n^{-n/\alpha}x^n$ as $x\longrightarrow +\infty$.

**What I tried:**

I tried to use the summation by parts formula but that but cannot evaluate the new expressions properly.
I also tried to compare with an integral but the expression is still hard to evaluate.

Comment: Giving some motivation why anybody would want to consider that might increase your chances for an answer considerably.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "an equivalent" in this context?